# Show element once only after mouse left

Tags: javascript, jquery

stackoverflow!

Everyone know good-guy-mouseout and good-guy-mouseleave

I decided to expand my function and wrote something like this:

```
    $("div").click(function(){
    $(this).on('mouseleave', function(){
            alert("Hello, bro");
        });
});
```

What I want? Well, I click on the element, do some stuff and when I leave jQuery says: "hello, bro!"

BUT!

If i close the dialog and then return to my lovely element with my cursor the wild dialog will appear again. But it should appear ONLY after click on the element.

Have you guys any suggest?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').click(function(){ //Setup the click
    $(this).one('mouseleave', function(){ //Use the 'one' style rather than @Bala's method
        alert('Hello, bro');
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, meeting a new feature. Now I want to avoid appearing multiple dialogues after multiple clicks on the element. You know, if you click on the block ten times, ten windows will appear. Of course I understand how the click event works, but I need to avoid this. 

So, I can clicked a lot of times on the element, but only if I leave the element - the dialog appears ONLY one time. 

Using "one()" will not work in this example, because I need to change the element after every click, but as soon as I leave the element the wild window must appear again and only ONE time!

Comment: $('#foo').bind({
  click: function() {
    //do_staff
  },
  mouseenter: function() {
    //do_staff
  }
});

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you click the div, you have to fire the mouse leave event. Again you click it also fires two times so it will be bind ..if you are off and on it will fire one time.  And don't use direct div element. You have to use any selector like id,class

```
$("div").click(function(){
    $(this).off('mouseleave');

    $(this).on('mouseleave', function(){
        alert("Hello, bro");
        $(this).off('mouseleave');
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't work correct. I clicked the <div> element, left my mouse and the wild dialog appeared, that's right. And when I moved my mouse again on the element, the dialog appeared BUT I didn't clicked the element!

Comment: Now i am updated.. then You have to off the event when it is not use

Comment: `.off()` is messy for this.  What if there are other click event handlers assigned?  It will remove them as well.  jsthornton's answer is better, using `.one()`